# Complex SQL query for a large record set

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have 3 tables. Lets start by explaining the first one

```
tblDistance: (airport1, airport2, distance) // airport1 and airport 2 are airport codes
```

This table contains the distances in miles between all airports of America there are a total of 3745 airports and the distances were calculated using a nested for loop and with each loop the counter was decremented. So for the 1st airport we calculated 3744 distances. For the second we calculated 3743 distances as we have already calculated its distance in the first loop with the first airport. Now lets say the first airport was **Animas Air Park(K00C)** and the second aiport is **Broadus Airport(K00F)**. The records would appear in tblDistance as

```
(KOOC, other3744aiports, distance)
```

For second airport

```
(K00C, K00F, distance) //This one record has been already calculated in 1st iteration of the loop
(KOOF, other3743aiports, distance)
```

So except for the 1st airport if we want to find all the distances for a particular airport lets say K00F we need a union query given below.

```
(SELECT * FROM tblDistances WHERE tblDistances.airport1 = 'K00F')
UNION ALL 
(SELECT * FROM tblDistances WHERE  tblDistances.airport2 = 'K00F');
```

I hope I have explained it clearly. Now lets come to the other 2 tables.  They are called **tblHave** and **tblNeed**

```
tblHave: (departure, departCode, arrival, arrivalCode, flightDate)
tblNeed: (departure, departCode, arrival, arrivalCode, flightDate)
```

Departure is the name of the airport from which the flight will depart and the **departCode(K00C, K00F)** is the code of the airport and same goes for arrival and arrivalCode.

Assume that we have a flight from (departure) **San Francisco Intl (KSFO)** to (arrival) **South Bend Rgnl (KSBN)** in the tblNeed. Now comes the real problem we have to find all the flights in the **tblHave** that are

1. On the same date as the given flight and
2. Departure airport is **(KSFO)** or within 500 miles of **San Francisco Intl (KSFO)** using union as explined above (lets call it qryDepart) AND
3. Arrival airport is **(KSBN)** or within 500 miles of **South Bend Rgnl (KSBN)** using union as explined above (lets call it qryArrival)

Sample qryArrival

```
SELECT tblDistances.airport2 as nearBy
FROM tblDistances
WHERE  tblDistances.airport1 = 'KSFO' AND (((Abs([tblDistances].[distance]))<=500)) 
UNION ALL SELECT tblDistances.airport1 as nearBy
FROM tblDistances
WHERE  tblDistances.airport2 = 'KSFO' AND (((Abs([tblDistances].[distance]))<=500));
```

I cannot figure out how can I find this and also the total no.of distance commbinations for all airports is more than 7 million. The records are in Access database. What I have figure is that I find nearby departure airports and nearby arrival airports from tblDistances and then use the IN clause to find the final results

```
Select * from tblHave where arrivalCode IN (qryArrival) AND departCode IN (qryDepart) AND Date = #dd/mm/yyyy#;
```

this is not working and the union takes too much time as the no of records is very large.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `UNION` here. You can do it in one query which should cut your execution time in half at least since you won't be checking every record twice. You can use a nested `iif` statement to determine which field to use for `nearBy`, and then change your `WHERE` to check both fields of the record. Like this:

```
SELECT 
    iif(
        tblDistances.airport = 'KSFO',
        tblDistances.airport2,
            iif(tblDistances.airport2 = 'KSFO',
                tblDistances.airport1,
                null)
        ) as nearBy
FROM tblDistances
WHERE  
    (
        tblDistances.airport1 = 'KSFO'
        OR tblDistances.airport2 = 'KSFO'
    )
    AND (((Abs([tblDistances].[distance]))<=500))
```

Which would be much easier to read if you used a `CASE` statement, but Access doesn't support `CASE`. The above query does the same thing as:

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN tblDistances.airport1 = 'KSFO' then tblDistances.airport2 
        WHEN tblDistances.airport2 = 'KSFO' then tblDistances.airport1
    END as nearBy
FROM tblDistances
WHERE  
    (
        tblDistances.airport1 = 'KSFO'
        OR tblDistances.airport2 = 'KSFO'
    )
    AND (((Abs([tblDistances].[distance]))<=500))
```

Comment: actually the union query takes less time than the one suggested by you. For proof watch the video here https://drive.google.com/open?id=12x0QyimOPWsF45X9Dgy0EY3bQ3-WK-Pl